# Create pointer to parent object in deserialization process in C#

Tags: c#, reference, serialization, parent-child

I have a classes like:

```
[Serializable]
public class child {
     public Parent parent;
}

[Serializable]
public class Parent {
  public List<child> children;
}
```

When I deserialize Parent, I want each of each children to have a reference to it's parent.  Question is, where in the deserialization process can I set the child's "parent" pointer?  I can't seem to use a custom constructor for child, because deserialization always uses the default constructor.  If I implement ISerializable, then it seems that the child objects have already been created by the time the parent is created.  Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: As said, binary serialization handles this automatically.

Answer (score 10):

Circular references are handled differently for the `BinaryFormatter`, `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer`.

The [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) supports circular references by default, no work required:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[Serializable]
public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Parent parent;
}

[Serializable]
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id;

    public List<Child> Children;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Child c1 = new Child { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        Child c2 = new Child { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

        Parent p = new Parent { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Children = new List<Child> { c1, c2 } };

        c1.parent = p;
        c2.parent = p;

        using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream1, p);
            stream1.Position = 0;

            var deserializedParent = formatter.Deserialize(stream1) as Parent;
            foreach (var child in deserializedParent.Children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Child Id: {0}, Parent Id: {1}", child.Id, child.parent.Id);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When using the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), avoid the circular refernce by not serializing the child's reference to the parent and ensure that the relationship is fixed during the deserialization process. This is done by implementing the [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface and handling serialization and deserialization.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerialization
{

    [Serializable]
    public class Child
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore] // Don't serialize the reference to the parent
        public Parent parent;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Parent : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public List<Child> Children;

        public Guid Id;

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            XElement xml = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
            if (xml != null)
            {
                // Deserialize Children
                Children = 
                    xml.Descendants("Child")
                       .Select(x => new Child() { Id = Guid.Parse(x.Element("Id").Value), parent = this })
                       .ToList();

                // Deserialize Id
                Id = Guid.Parse(xml.Attribute("Id").Value); 
            }
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            // Serialize Id
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Id", Id.ToString());

            // Serialize Children
            XmlSerializer childSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child));
            foreach (Child child in Children)
            {
                childSerializer.Serialize(writer, child);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Child c1 = new Child { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
            Child c2 = new Child { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

            Parent p = new Parent { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Children = new List<Child> { c1, c2 } };

            c1.parent = p;
            c2.parent = p;

            using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent), new Type[] { typeof(Child) }) ;
                formatter.Serialize(stream1, p);
                stream1.Position = 0;

                stream1.Position = 0;

                var deserializedParent = formatter.Deserialize(stream1) as Parent;
                foreach (var child in deserializedParent.Children)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Child Id: {0}, Parent Id: {1}", child.Id,  child.parent.Id ));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

When using the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), use the [IsReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056.aspx) property of the `DataContract` attribute to enable reference tracking when serializing and deserializing DataContracts.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Child
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Parent parent;
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Parent
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id;

    [DataMember]
    public List<Child> Children;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Child c1 = new Child { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        Child c2 = new Child { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

        Parent p = new Parent { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Children = new List<Child> { c1, c2 } };

        c1.parent = p;
        c2.parent = p;

        using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractSerializer formatter = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Parent));
            formatter.WriteObject(stream1, p);
            stream1.Position = 0;

            var deserializedParent = formatter.ReadObject(stream1) as Parent;
            foreach (var child in deserializedParent.Children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Child Id: {0}, Parent Id: {1}", child.Id, child.parent.Id);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you leave it alone and let Parent be a public read/write property of the Child class, .NET automatic serialization process will handle it properly.

Comment: For binary serialization, properties are not considered. Only fields.  But yes, it will still be handled automatically.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, and can't find any reference to this anywhere. Is there any documentation on the matter?

Answer (score 3):

If the automatic deserialization doesn't work, you could have your Parent class implement the [IDeserializationCallback interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y2ty1t2.aspx), and update the children in the [OnDeserialization method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.ondeserialization.aspx).

```
[Serializable]
class Parent : IDeserializationCallback 
{
  public List<child> children;

  void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender) 
  {
    if (null != children)
    {
      children.ForEach(c => c.parent = this);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this (sort of) by overriding the Add method in the child object's collection class, to 'set" a property value in the child class with the unique identifer of the parent object

```
 public class Connections: List<Connection>
    {       public new void Add(Connection connection)
        {
            connection.ApplicationName = ApplicationName;
            base.Add(connection);
        }
    }
```