# getting of the parent object using DataContractSerializer during deserialization

Tags: datacontractserializer

More or less the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353558/) but for DataContractSerializer rather than Serializable.

I explicitly do not want to be serializing parent references.

Also I would really rather the object's parent be bound before the children are constructed.

BTW: I'm using XML if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

If you know the universe of child types, you can implement a surrogate to special-case the non-child types and essentially 'skip' the parent (i.e., non-child) types during serialization. As an example, see the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540.aspx [Data Contract Surrogate] sample. Another option -- if you're using WCF 4 now -- is to use a DataContractResolver for type resolution and redirection. Again, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807504.aspx [Data Contract Resolve Sample] for a reference!

Cheers.